# Bootstrap 3 & LESS Semantic Column Ordering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, semantic-markup

In Bootstrap 3 I am able to do the follow (for semantic markup):

```
.div1 {
    .make-xs-column(12);
}
.div2 {
    .make-xs-column(12);
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
    <!-- Stuff Goes Here -->
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <!-- More Stuff Goes Here -->
</div>
```

Within inline class definitions I can change the order of div1 and div2 by doing:

```
<div class="div1 col-xs-push-12">
</div>
<div class="div2 col-xs-pull-12">
</div>
```

Is it possible to change the column ordering with LESS mixins? Or is this feature not currently available? Would it be good practice to do something like this?:

```
.div1 {
    .make-xs-column(12);
    .col-sm-push-12;
}
.div2 {
    .make-xs-column(12);
    .col-sm-pull-12;
}
```

**Edited:** I meant to ask about xs columns rather than sm. Should I do pull and push on sm+ devices and reverse the order of my markup?

Comment: if you defined col-sm-push-12 as a mixin then you can use .col-sm-push-12. In your example col-sm-push-12 is a class not a mixin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same story as with `.make-*-column()`, i.e. [there're](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less) `.make-*-column-offset` `.make-*-column-push` and `.make-*-column-pull` mixins.